# Error while trying to connect to azure event hub using amqp

Tags: python, azure, qpid, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to connect as subscriber (for recieving messages) to an azure event hub using python and the proton library.

I have found an example code and eventually got to:

```
import sys
import optparse
from proton import *
import urllib


mng = Messenger()
mng.start()

nb_partitions = 8
sasKeyName = "NAME"
sasPolicyKey = "KEY"
# safeSasPolicyKey = urllib.quote(sasPolicyKey, "")
safeSasPolicyKey = sasPolicyKey

args = []
for i in range(0, nb_partitions):
    address = "amqps://%s:%s@clienteventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/ConsumerGroups/$Default" % (
        sasKeyName, safeSasPolicyKey)
    args.append(address + "/Partitions/" + str(i))

print(args)

for a in args:
    # mng.subscribe(a)
    mng.subscribe(a)
    print "Subscribed to %s" % (a)

msg = Message()
while True:
    mng.recv()
    while mng.incoming:
        try:
            mng.get(msg)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        else:
            print msg.address, msg.subject or "(no subject)", msg.properties, msg.body
```

I'm running this code on macosx using python-qpid-proton (0.10) installed using pip.

but i can't get any messages of the event-hub I do know i send a message each minute from a different script which does work.
I do the get following output that i printed

> Subscribed to
>   amqps://NAME:KEY@clienteventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/0
>   Subscribed to
>   amqps://NAME:KEY@clienteventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/1
>   Subscribed to
>   amqps://NAME:KEY@clienteventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/2
>   Subscribed to
>   amqps://NAME:KEY@clienteventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/3
>   Subscribed to
>   amqps://NAME:KEY@clienteventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/4
>   Subscribed to
>   amqps://NAME:KEY@clienteventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/5
>   Subscribed to
>   amqps://NAME:KEY@clienteventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/6
>   Subscribed to
>   amqps://NAME:KEY@clienteventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/NAME/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/7

Do you know why this code fails to work?
Thanks

Comment: I reproduced the issue. And I tried to follow the doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj841070.aspx to receive messages from EventHubs,, but failed. I don't find any other docs for consuming events from EventHubs in Python. So I suggest to use EventProcessorHost(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/#receive-messages-with-eventprocessorhost) for C#/.Net to do it.

Comment: So you say i should open it up as a bug with azure support?

Comment: Could you set the following environment variable? It should show the Proton protocol trace: export PN_TRACE_FRM=true

Answer (score 0):

There could be  multiple reasons why you are not able to receive messages. 
this could also be one of the reason Please do check  **outbound ports 5671 /9352** used by the Event hub are not  blocked by firewall .

Refer to this  [link](http://thecodetricks.blogspot.in/2015/10/azure-event-hub-on-premise-blocked.html)

Comment: I actually have those ports open and i am able to send messages using amqp and using the sdk and using the rest api. also i have checked the router already (sadly no firewall on my end)

Answer (score -1):

change consumer group --> `$Default` to `$default`

```
address = "amqps://%s:%s@%s.servicebus.windows.net/%s/ConsumerGroups/$default" % (sasKeyName, safeSasPolicyKey,name_space,eventhub)
```